i already created the usersdb but it does not show
i already created the usersdb but it does not show
mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.19
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("9bea0d75-362b-4f55-ac5d-6c709d2ddb36") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.19
Server has startup warnings: 
2024-05-03T16:48:49.803+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] 
2024-05-03T16:48:49.803+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2024-05-03T16:48:49.803+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2024-05-03T16:50:31.149+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2024-05-03T16:50:31.149+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2024-05-03T16:50:31.149+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2024-05-03T16:50:31.149+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2024-05-03T16:50:31.150+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2024-05-03T16:50:31.150+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2024-05-03T16:50:31.150+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2024-05-03T16:50:31.150+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
> use userdb
switched to db userdb
> show collections
> db.users.find()
> 


MongoDB won't actually create the database until you insert some data into it.
